# Playwright Not Automated

Tags: python, browser-automation, playwright

I am trying to automate a task with playwright and realized that the task won't automate unless my mouse is over the open browser. Is this normal or is there some sort of paradigm I'm following? The only thing it will automate without mouse hover is "screenshot" according to my current knowledge.

Comment: Can you share the code you have and what are you trying to do, so we can assess what is the blocker?

Comment: @JoãoFarias

The Code:
• browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
• context = browser.new_context()
• page = context.new_page()
• page.goto("https://www.xbox.com/en-US/consoles/all-consoles#shop")
• print("Page Loaded...")

It goes to the page but won't print "Page Loaded" until I manually click the page itself. What's weird is that I tested this on google.com in the same format, but google was able to automate without clicking the page itself.